# Subversion 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, webdav, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to check out a Subversion repository. My other two subversion clients don't have issues trying to check out. They are however in another network setup.

I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.7.5 64 bit (also tried the newest 1.7.7 64 bit).

When I do this I get the following error:

> Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to REPORT request for '/svn/cosara2/!svn/vcc/default'

In other posts I found that there could be a problem with an already existing folder. I've made sure there is no such folder.

The Subversion server is set up to use WebDav so the SVN URL is like `http://some/url/to/svn/repo/branch`

Could this be an issue with an HTTP proxy webserver? Any other thoughts?

Comment: Yes, the proxy server is the most likely reason. Proxy server handles the request itself rather than building a tunnel (like HTTPS proxies do), and when handing that request it seems to either not like the HTTP verb (command) or to send the wrong verb to the SVN server.

Comment: did you add the proxy in Tsvns proxy configuration?

Comment: @PeterParker I did add the proxy in Tsvns but this does not resolve the problem. I read something on the TortoiseSVN about a proxy blocking DAV requests. I assume that this will be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue by setting up HTTPS for the SVN repository. DAV was not allowed by the proxy server but since the proxy server cannot interpret HTTPS it can not block DAV.